# how to get post.user.username using self.kwargs.get in Python Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have the below working code in my accounts DetailView so it shows the rating for each user in the users profile page

**profile view**

```
context['ratings_list'] = Ratings.objects.filter(rating_for__username__iexact=    
    self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

I want to use the same code in my posts list view where the username will be post.user.username.

**Example:** *Below is how I want the post list page looks it has multiple posts*

```
Post 1 
by Samir Tendulkar. Samir Tendulkar's rating: 8/10 

Post 2 
by John Doe. John Doe's rating: 7/10
```

**post view** *Can I keep the same view as above*

```
context['ratings_list'] = Rating.objects.filter(rating_for__username__iexact=
    self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

**rating model:**

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    rating_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='rating_from')
    rating_for = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='rating_for')
```

**post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()

   def user_rating(self):
    counter = 0
    total_ratings = 0
    for item in Rating.objects.filter(rating_for=self.user.username):
        counter += 1
        total_ratings += int(item.ratings)
        user_rating = total_ratings / counter
        return user_rating
```

In my **profile template** (Which is actually the User's Profile Template)

```
{% if rating_list %}
     Rating: {% for rating in rating_list|slice:":1" %}
     {{ rating.average_rating }} / 10 {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     User has no rating yet
{% endif %}
```

*I am not sure how to get post ListView template*

Comment: try `post.user.rating_set.all()`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal where exacty do I use `post.user.rating_set.all()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood what you're asking, it may be easiest to add a `user_rating` property to your `Post` model, which you can then access from your `Post` list template. For example:

**Post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()

    @property
    def user_rating(self):
        return Rating.objects.get(rating_for=self.user)
```

Then in your `Post` list template:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <div>
        <span><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></span><br>
        <span>by {{ post.user.username }}, rating: {{ post.user_rating.average_rating }} / 10</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this I get `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'amanda'` I also tried `{{ post.user_rating|floatformat }}`

Comment: Sorry I'd missed the call to `average_rating` in the template. Answer now updated.

Comment: I think we are almost there more error `get() returned more than one Rating -- it returned 2!` I have edited my post.model in the question. What do you think of that but that again gives me a `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'amanda'` error

Comment: Ok I think it’s just a case of passing the correct argument to `rating_for`. That foreign key relationship needs the user, not the username. So change your code to `for item in Rating.objects.filter(rating_for=self.user)`

Comment: thank you for that where do I add this in the post.models ? Can you edit your answer to reflect that so I understand this a bit better